# Load GPX file in android studio DDMS

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, ddms, gpx

I am trying to upload GPX file to my android device through Android Debug Monitor (DDMS).

My process:

`Tools > Android > Monitor (DDMS included)
Then I selected my android device`

**NOTE**: This is a real device not the emulator device. So is it possible to upload to an actual device? I know that Xcode allows you to do that.

`So after selecting my device, clicked on Emulator Control.
But everything was grayed out in that box. I could not click on GPX tab`
`

It is not grayed out if the device I selected is the emulator not the real device.

`I also checked under Windows > other views > Android > Emulator Control, It is grayed out there as well`

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Or is there another way in my device to mock device gps movement in real device??

Answer (score 0):

I believe on a real device you have to use a mock location provider.

One I found that seems pretty good https://github.com/johncarpenter/Android-GPX-Mock-Location-Provider

In the new Location Client google IO session google had their own but i guess its not published?

I highly recommend watching the IO Session https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc